# How do I clean up the Add/Remove Programs List?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-registry

hoping you can help me with something.

I'm running a fairly basic Boot SSD + Storage HDD setup for my PC, and I recently had my storage HDD fail on me. I've sent it to the shop to see what I can restore for cheap, but all my important files are safely backed up, so no problems there.

Now, I've bought a new Storage HDD and installed/formatted it properly, so it's nice and clean, with all the old programs I installed but stopped using no longer taking up space in it. Hurrah. However, all those programs currently still show up in my Add/Remove programs list, and since I'm hardly going to install them again, I'd prefer them gone from that list - keeping them there is harmless, of course, but having them there ignites an itch in the back of my mind. Like taking a shower and still having a nagging feeling of dirt somewhere I can't reach.

Is there a way to easily clean up that list of Add/Remove programs, and correct the registry files without having to do it manually (I have a large amount of those programs, so going through by hand is going to be a pain) or using a registry cleaner (I don't really feel like trusting a third party software with my PC's registry)?

Comment: Try [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft doesn't advertise any programs that automatically clean missing programs from your registry.  So if you don't trust ANY third parties, you're stuck doing it yourself one-by-one.

If there are any that you aren't able to remove yourself, there are a couple of Microsoft utilities [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.utilityspotlight.aspx) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en?wa=wsignin1.0).

EDIT: I marked this answer as Community Wiki because I realize it doesn't solve the problem.